# How to get HTTPS on AKS without ingress

Tags: nginx, https, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

My problem is simple. I have an AKS deployment with a LoadBalancer service that needs to use HTTPS with a certificate.

How do I do this?

Everything I'm seeing online involves Ingress and nginx-ingress in particular.

But my deployment is not a website, it's a Dropwizard service with a REST API on one port and an admin service on another port. I don't want to map the ports to a path on port 80, I want to keep the ports as is.  Why is HTTPS tied to ingress?

I just want HTTPS with a certificate and nothing more changed, is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sidecar container with nginx with the correct certificates (possible loaded off a Secret or a ConfigMap) will do the job without ingress. [This](https://vorozhko.net/kubernetes-sidecar-pattern-nginx-ssl-proxy-for-nodejs) seems to be a good example, using [nginx-ssl-proxy container](https://hub.docker.com/r/ployst/nginx-ssl-proxy/).

Comment: This is definitely the kind of thing I'm looking for thanks. I'm waiting to pick an answer when I can actually get something working, but this looks closest so far

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's right as of this writing an Ingress will currently work either on port 80 or port 443, potentially it can be extended to use any port because [nginx](https://nginx.org/), [Traefik](https://traefik.io/), [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/), etc can all listen on different ports.

So you are down to either a [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#loadbalancer) or a [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#nodeport) type of service.  Type LoadBalancer will not work directly with TLS since the Azure load balancers are [layer 4](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11424). So you will have to use [Application Gateway](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/) and it's preferred to use an [internal load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb) for security reasons.

Since you are using Azure you can run something like this (assuming that your K8s cluster is configured the right way to use the Azure cloud provider, either the `--cloud-provider` option or the cloud-controller-manager):

```
$ cat <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: your-app
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: <your-port>
  selector:
    app: your-app
EOF | kubectl apply -f -
```

and that will create an Azure load balancer on the port you like for your service. Behind the scenes, the load balancer will point to a port on the nodes and within the nodes, there will be firewall rules that will route to your container. Then you can configure [Application Gateway](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/). [Here's](https://rinormaloku.com/prohibiting-direct-access-microservices-aks/) a good article describing it but using port 80, you will have to change it use port 443 and configuring the TLS certs, and the Application Gateway also supports [end to end TLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#does-application-gateway-also-support-re-encryption-of-traffic-to-the-backend) in case you want to terminate TLS directly on your app too.

The other option is NodePort, and you can run something like this:

```
$ kubectl expose deployment <deployment-name> --type=NodePort
```

Then Kubernetes will pick a random port on all your nodes where you can send traffic to your service listening on `<your-port>`. So, in this case, you will have to manually create a load balancer with TLS or a traffic source that listens on TLS `<your-port>` and forwards it to a NodePort on all your nodes, this load balancer can be anything like haproxy, nginx, Traefik or something else that supports terminating TLS. And you can also use the [Application Gateway](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/) to forward directly to your node ports, in other words, define a listener that listens on the NodePort of your cluster.

Comment: Yes, I already am using a LoadBalancer service with dns and public ip. I only added Ingress for https, you answer doesn't address https.

Comment: Added more TLS details, let me know if you don't understand anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182610/discussion-between-novaterata-and-rico).